# Using spies in non testing code in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tracking

I recently dug a little deeper into unit testing. I was wondering if there is a way to use spies in production code as well. I've a tracking service. It would be nice to access other services and maybe even controllers, without haveing to alter their code.

Is there a way to spy on methods being called from services and controllers in the application code and what would be the best way to do so?

**EDIT**
Atm. I'm using this pattern for spying on services:

> ```
>            var vSetFNTrigger = function (sEvent, fnTrigger) {
>                 fnTrigger.obj[fnTrigger.sMethod] = (function () {
>                     var fnCached = fnTrigger.obj[fnTrigger.sMethod];
>                     return function () {
>                         $rootScope.$broadcast(sEvent, {});
>                         return fnCached.apply(this, arguments);                            
>                     };
>                 })(); 
>             };
> ```

```
                fnTrigger: {
                    obj: formData, // the service
                    sMethod: 'qPost' // the method to spy on
                },
```

**EDIT 2**
I forgot to add a return to the inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be nothing stopping you from doing this, although I think it is the wrong tool for the job.

If you are in Angular, you should consider using a decorator pattern.  You can even use the [provider decorator](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#decorator) to intercept pretty much anything in Angular.

For instance, you might have a spy function that looks like this:

```
function createSpy(serviceName, source, spyNames, rootScope) {
    var spy = angular.extend(angular.isFunction(source) ? function () {
        console.log("Called " + serviceName + '()', arguments);
        // broadcast with rootScope
        return source.apply(source, arguments);
    } : {}, source);

    spyNames.forEach(function(name) {
        var original = spy[name];
        spy[name] = function() {
            console.log("Called " + serviceName + '.' + name, arguments);
            // broadcast with rootScope
            return original.apply(spy, arguments);
        };
    });

    return spy;
}
```

Then, you can create a generic function to generate a decorator:

```
function decorateWithSpy($provide, service, spyNames) {
    $provide.decorator(service, function($delegate, $rootScope) {
        return createSpy(service, $delegate, spyNames, $rootScope);
    });
}
```

You can configure your spies like this:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
    decorateWithSpy($provide, '$http', ['get']);
    decorateWithSpy($provide, '$compile', []); 
});
```

Doing this causes all of my `$http` and `$compile` functions to get printed to the console.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I totally forgot they exist :)

Comment: But its not really what I wanted. I dont want to alter the service functions in any way, I just want to add event handlers, to specfic actions in different part of the app and I want to do the tracking in a single separated place.

Comment: I suppose I am confused.  The decorator doesn't alter the service functions.  It wraps them.  Spying, however, does modify the existing service.  Jasmine Spies modify the existing service and so does the code you are proposing.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the functionality of the decorator correctly. Wouldn't I have to rewrite functions the same way, if I would want to watch them? I would be very nice if you could provide an example for using the decorator as substitute for a spy ;)

But in general what I would like to avoid is having to write a decorator for every single service I want to track.

Comment: An example?  Ha!  This was fun to create :)  This works pretty well.  It wraps the original service in a derived object that instruments the code.  It doesn't touch the original service at all :)

Comment: That looks really really nice :). I'll try to implement and to understand it a little bit better tomorrow and give you feedback!

Comment: Sorry for tacking back the correct answer for now, but the problem is, that I can't inject any services into the config function of angular. That means not only that I can't use $rootScope, but also that I cant track any service from there.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I'm not following. What services can't you spy on?  What are you trying to do, exactly?  The `angular.config` step allows you to create your decorators, but you are correct.  At that step, you can't get at any concrete services.  The decorator gets called when resolving the concrete services, however.  Can't you use the `angular.injector` to get the `$rootScope` at that time?

Comment: Actually, you can inject `$rootScope` at decoration resolution... I've updated my example to show how to pass the `$rootScope` into your spy function... `provide.decorator(service, function($delegate, $rootScope) {})`  Unless I'm missing something?